# Stripe - No API key provided (Laravel 5.1)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments

I have problem with providing the Stripe API key. Everything is included, packages, all dependencies...

The error message I get: No API key provided. (HINT: set your API key using "Stripe::setApiKey()". You can generate API keys from the Stripe web interface. See https://stripe.com/api for details, or email support@stripe.com if you have any questions.

Controller:

```
    public function upgradeBronze() {

        $bid = Session::get('builderId');

        Stripe::setApiKey(env('KEY_SECRET'));
        $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

        // Create the charge on Stripe's servers - this will charge the user's card

        try {

            $user = \App\User::find($bid);
            $user->subscription('monthly')->create($token);
            return Redirect::route('builders-packages');

        } catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
            return Redirect::route('builders-packages');
        }

}
```

Error SS: http://pokit.org/get/img/5f7886d0d9a50ecf349312225c8c47ea.jpg

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

It seems that Stripe integration doesn't work fine on Laravel 5.1 version, if you follow the default documentation you probably won't succeed.

In this case the solution was to put the stripe api key into AppServiceProvider, into register() class.

Comment: Isn't it required to be put in config?

Comment: @Volatil3 Like i said, If you follow the default instructions you won't succeed. Yes it says you need to put in config file, but other solution is this...

Comment: `5.1.10` does seem to resolve the issue. However, I can't catch Stripe error.

Comment: @sk4yb3n I have set in register function of AppServiceProvider like `Stripe::setApiKey('pk_test_mytesting_key');` but it isn't working either

Answer (score 0):

Set the Stripe API key from `stripe.php` like

```php
public static $apiKey='sk_test_your api_key';
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting stripe API keys in my .env file (worked for me, Laravel 5.8):

`STRIPE_KEY=your pk key here`

`STRIPE_SECRET=your sk key here`