# Laravel: Stripe No API key provided. (HINT: set your API key using Stripe::setApiKey()

Tags: laravel-5, stripe-payments

Yes, I know, there is an exact same question there but the "solution" is not approved nor specified as it should.

So:
1) I installed the stripe library v.3.0 by php composer.phar require stripe/etc

and it installed ok, (otherwise I wouldn't have actually received that error)

2) I have the public test key in the blade Form in the Head section alright

3) Then at the controller I included inside the public function that receives the data from the Form the following: (no problem not my real secret key)

```
$token = Input::get('stripeToken');
Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_1VJeJsdfsdgdgVbJODDDD");
```

3) I also put it in the .env file as

```
STRIPE_API_SECRET='sk_test_1VJeJsvj7l2ft2eXXsevDD'
```

and made a call from the config/services.php as

```
'stripe' => [
        'model'  => App\User::class,
        'key'    => '',
        'secret' => env('STRIPE_API_SECRET'),
    ],
```

but I keep getting that error.

The other same question at SO says that it has "solved" it by:

```
the solution was to put the stripe api key into AppServiceProvider, into register() class.
```

That is completely vague, inaccurate and don't know what he is talking about.

Anyone knows? thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue, and worked around it by setting the key manually in my controller constructor like so:

```
class SubscriptionController extends Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));
    }

    public function getPlans() {
        dd(Plan::all());
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but only for the specific controller mentioned here. If you want to make sure the error won't happen no matter where Stripe API calls are made, don't use this (unless you want to add it to every single controller in your app).

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the `Billable` code:

```
/**
 * Get the Stripe API key.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public static function getStripeKey()
{
    return static::$stripeKey ?: getenv('STRIPE_SECRET');
}

/**
 * Set the Stripe API key.
 *
 * @param  string  $key
 * @return void
 */
public static function setStripeKey($key)
{
    static::$stripeKey = $key;
}
```

It wants either the static variable or the `STRIPE_SECRET` environment variable to be defined.

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32279966/89771) is a bit vague, but offers a solution. In your `AppServiceProvider`:

```
public function register()
{
    \App\Models\User::setStripeKey(\Config::get('services.stripe.secret'));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to clear cache

```
php artisan config:cache
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/configuration#configuration-caching

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it was because 'stripe' was configured twice in config/services/php. Are you really sure that config/services.php only has one instance of 'stripe' in there?

Here's my example config/services.php, that's working with Stripe, for reference:

```
<?php
return [
'mandrill' => [
    'secret' => env('MANDRILL_SECRET'),
],

'ses' => [
    'key'    => env('SES_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('SES_SECRET'),
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
],

'stripe' => [
    'model'  => 'App\Models\User',
    'key'    => env('STRIPE_API_PUBLIC'),
    'secret' => env('STRIPE_API_SECRET'),
],
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Set  public static $apiKey='sk_test_your api key'; from stripe.php

Answer (score 0):

Comprehensive answer, solving it for the entire application:

`.env` file:

```
STRIPE_KEY=pk_live_exampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexample
STRIPE_SECRET=sk_live_exampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexampleexample
```

`config\services.php` file:

```
'stripe' => [
    [...]
    'key' => env('STRIPE_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('STRIPE_SECRET'),
],
```

`app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php` file:

```
public function boot()
{
    [...]
    Stripe::setApiKey(config('services.stripe.secret'));
    [...]
}
```

Afterwards, you can also run, on command line:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

---

Explanation:

- I use the `boot()` method instead of `register()` suggested in other answers for reasons explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49782349/difference-between-boot-and-register-method-of-app-service-provider-class-in-lar/).
- `php artisan config:clear` is not always necessary, but makes sure you're not using cached configuration, preventing the app picking up the changes added above.